# Error in django admin "Operational error no such column"

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, pycharm

I am starting with Django development i am following http://www.tangowithdjango.com/ for basic tutorial as i am making some changes into given example i fall into this problem.

Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:
no such column: CodingRat_page.subcategory_id
[image]

my models.py is as following.

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Page(models.Model):
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When i check

```
sqlall CodingRat
```

following is the output
[image]

Where i can see subcategory_id.
I have run makemigration migration command also still problem exists.I can access other page category and subcategory.

I am using django1.8, pycharm4.5.4 and python3.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you have to do manage.py makemigrations [appname] followed by manage.py migrate it's not clear from your statement whether you have done both steps

Comment: I have run both command in same order but no success

Comment: Since this is only a tutorial and there's nothing you can't afford to lose, just drop all the tables. Clear out the migrations folder, and run those commands again.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried most of suggested command on stackoverflow and other forums.

manage.py flush
mangae.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate 
manage.py syncdb 
and few other commands also nothing worked for me.

I deleted the default database and changed the db name in settings.py after this every thing worked like a charm. May be it can help someone.